# Cannot reformat Micro SD Card

Tags: linux, partition, io, gparted, sd-card

I need to reformat my micro SD card, however I am having some issues with it.  When I go the card on my computer, it displays the following message:

> The folder contents could not be displayed Sorry, could not display
>   all the contents of "5390-A1C4": Error when getting information for
>   file '/media/username/5390-A1C4/N└G1°l;╓.u▌%': Input/output error

I then try to open gparted to attempt to format it, but it only loads and does not open gparted.

I am using a micro sdhc named *5390-A1C4* mounted */media/username/5390-A1C4* with a filesystem type of msdos.  My OS is Linux Mint.  It is mounted at /dev/mmcblk0p1 and the device is /dev/mmcblk0.

Any help with solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Tell us the device where it is mounted.

Comment: No problem.  I just added it in an edit

Comment: The actual directory is of not much use, do you know the device? Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Is there a way for me to find out where it is mounted so that I can tell you?  It is a micro sdhc card in an sd card adapter in the sd card port in my laptop

Comment: if it mounts, `df` will show it, otherwise, reading the output of `dmesg`

Comment: got it.  /dev/mmcblk0p1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have it corrupted. With luck it is not definitively damaged.

The better way to deal with it is "zeroing it" and defining everything anew.

For that we zero it with dd:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 count=2
```

where /dev/mmcblk0 is the device where it is normally mounted. (/dev/mmcblk0p1 is actually the partition)

After the dd you can repartition it and format it again.

Comment: So then in my case, should I do *dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=512 count=2*

Comment: Nope, I actually changed the answer before reading this. /dev/mmcblk0 is the device, /dev/mmcblk0p1 is the partition. Common mistake to be fair.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my question to reflect that.  I will try it now!

Comment: (I edited your OP for technical correctness)

Comment: Perfect.  I was then able to open and reformat the card in gparted.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I would classify as bugs the fact that gparted and Disk Utility in Mac/OS/X are incapable of dealing with that kind of stuff.